# Data at csv not correctly Aligned

Tags: vb.net, csv, export

Good day im having some trouble when exporting data from datagrid to csv file.

```
Sub csv()

    Dim headers = (From header As DataGridViewColumn In dgShow.Columns.Cast(Of DataGridViewColumn)()
                   Select header.HeaderText).ToArray
    Dim rows = From row As DataGridViewRow In dgShow.Rows.Cast(Of DataGridViewRow)()
               Where Not row.IsNewRow
               Select Array.ConvertAll(row.Cells.Cast(Of DataGridViewCell).ToArray, Function(c) If(c.Value IsNot Nothing, c.Value.ToString, ""))
    Using sw As New IO.StreamWriter("export.csv")
        sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", headers))
        For Each r In rows
            sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", r))
        Next
    End Using
    Process.Start("export.csv")




End Sub
```

here is my sample code

here the data grid

[image: data grid]

inside csv file

[image: csv]

Comment: Clarify your question. What is the trouble you are facing?

Comment: when exporting to csv file it is not aligned correctly by row. as you can see in picture.

Comment: You need to debug your code.  You ALWAYS need to debug your code before posting a question here.  What you're seeing seems to suggest that some of your data contains commas or line breaks or both.  If you debug your code, you can actually look at the data as it is being used, even to the point of seeing exactly what characters are in it.  That's why VS includes a debugger.  The "I" in "IDE" stands for "integrated", which means all the tools you need, including the debugger, are included.

Comment: why do people goes here? to ask right? already debugged my program. and i just push my self in my exceeded knowledge. so im here to ask some question to add in my knowledge. im just a 12 year old boy BTW.

Comment: As @jmcilhinney said, you can debug your code. I am guessing that your first rows string have "\n" in them at the end. And that is why there are line breaks in the end. To resolve this, just apply a function which removes the line breaks and spaces from both sides of string before joining it to your csv file.  To be exact, before the line `sw.Writeline(String....))` , you need to modify the string `r`. Python has a function `strip` for that, there must be one for VB...

Comment: *"already debugged my program"*.  I have to ask what you actually did then, because you seem not to have looked at the actual data you're writing to the file.  If you're having trouble with writing data to a file, examining the data you're writing seems a fairly logical step, doesn't it?

Comment: @prime_hit, "\n" is a C-style representation of a line feed character and not something you'll see in VB.  If you examine a `String` containing a line feed using the debugger for VB, you'll see `vbLf` for just a line feed or `vbCrLf` for a line break comprised of a carriage return and a line feed.  The `String.TrimEnd` method allows you to remove any specified characters from the end of a `String`.

Comment: That said, an important question here is where these erroneous characters came from in the first place.  There's every chance that the real issue is the code that is reading the data into the grid in the first place.  For example, it is often the case that people code with `Option Strict Off`, which is the default but should be changed immediately and permanently, and they end up with the code silently treating line breaks containing two characters as just one character and leaving behind the additional character.  This is most common via misuse of the `String.Split` method.

Comment: @jmcilhinney Oh great! I actually don't use VB, I was just trying to guide him to the path he can take... I baiscally meant that there should be line ending character (or whatever there is in VB!) at the end of the first rows strings.... and thanks for cool info about VB!

Comment: I suspect that it is the misuse of `String.Split` that is the culprit in this case.  For instance, if you had a `String` containing the pcb and model values separated by a line break and used `theString.Split(Environment.NewLine)` to separate them with `Option Strict Off` then you would actually split just on the carriage return, leaving the model value with a leading line break on it.  You wouldn't see that character represented in the grid but it would be seen as a line separator if written to the CSV file, exactly as we are seeing here.

Comment: could have improved question with example csv format.

Comment: If that is the case, the solution here is to fix the code that reads the data in the first place.  That would involve turning `Option Strict On` (in the project properties and IDE options, so it is `On` by default in future) and then using `String.Split` properly.  The code I showed earlier would fail to compile with `Option Strict On` and a different overload would be required, which would actually split on the pair of characters, as intended.

Comment: sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", r).Replace(vbCrLf, [String].Empty))
thanks prime_hit i already fixed

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution:

```
sw.WriteLine(String.Join(",", r).Replace(vbCrLf, [String].Empty))
```